# Argument exception when creating new bitmap

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

I have a little problem , I can't get my code working , when I try the following :

```
        Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\NahNah\Desktop\HeightMap.png"
        IO.File.Create(filename)
        Dim h As New Structures.HeightMap(1, 10, 512)
        Dim graph As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
        Dim png As New Bitmap(filename)

        graph.DrawImage(png, Width, Height)
        h.Generate()
        graph = h.Draw(graph)
        graph.DrawImage(png, 1024, 1024)
        png.Save(filename)
```

I get an Argument exception at line

```
        Dim png As New Bitmap(filename)
```

As you can see , I don't really know what I am doing and I need help . Thanks

Comment: You need to say what the problem is, not just that you have one.

Comment: You subject says `argument exception` - Is that the error you are getting? On what line?

Comment: I edited , it's at the dim png as new bitmap(filename). I tried to change the *.png to .bmp but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it fails....

```
    IO.File.Create(filename)
    ......
    Dim png As New Bitmap(filename)
```

What do you expect to happen when you try to open an empty file like it was a valid bitmap?

Though I miss a lot of details (Structures and its parameters are a mistery, where do you get Width and Heigth....), I think you should follow this approach

```
Dim h As New Structures.HeightMap(1, 10, 512)
Using png As New Bitmap(Width, Height)   
    Using graph = Graphics.FromImage(png)
        h.Generate()
        graph.DrawImage(png, 1024, 1024)
        png.Save(filename)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Yes , thank you very much ! I need to understand what is the 'using' keyword ?

Comment: The Using statement is very important when you work with system resources like bitmaps. It guarantees that when you have finished to work with these resources they will be disposed (released to the system) [See docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)